# LDAP attribute to encode the language of human users mother tongue?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema, canonical-link

What would be the canonical attribute in an LDAP schema to encode the mother tongue (first language) of a user?

Interop with default/existing administration tools for Windows Active Directory would be a big plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'preferredLanguage' attribute of the inetOrgPerson (and AD's user) object class is what you are after.

As far as I know this field is not exposed by the default Windows admin tools. You would need a lower-level tool such as adsiedit.msc.

> 2.7.  Preferred Language
>
> Used to indicate an individual's
>   preferred written or spoken
>   language.  This is useful for
>   international correspondence or human-
>   computer interaction.  Values for this
>   attribute type MUST conform to    the
>   definition of the Accept-Language
>   header field defined in    [RFC2068]
>   with one exception:  the sequence
>   "Accept-Language" ":"    should be
>   omitted.  This is a single valued
>   attribute type.
>
> ```
> ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.39
>   NAME 'preferredLanguage'
>   DESC 'preferred written or spoken language for a person'
>   EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
>   SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
>   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
>   SINGLE-VALUE )
> )
> ```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Note that this mechanism will only work for individual updates. You would need to write a script if you want to update the preferredLanguage for more than one user in Active Directory.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 2798](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2798.html) defines the preferredLanguage attribute. Here is its definition from OpenLDAP:

```
# preferredLanguage
# Used to indicate an individual's preferred written or spoken
# language.  This is useful for international correspondence or human-
# computer interaction.  Values for this attribute type MUST conform to
# the definition of the Accept-Language header field defined in
# [RFC2068] with one exception:  the sequence "Accept-Language" ":"
# should be omitted.  This is a single valued attribute type.
attributetype ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.39
        NAME 'preferredLanguage'
        DESC 'RFC2798: preferred written or spoken language for a person'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
        SINGLE-VALUE )
```